# What are the allowed values for Huawei AdsKit `AdParam.Builder`?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-ads

What are the allowed enum values in [`AdParam.Builder`](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/ads-api-adparam-builder#setGender), eg. `setGender(int value)`?

I've tried using `1` and `2`, but having `Root obj class .. is invalid` in the log:

```
2021-01-13 00:20:22.041 2138-2324 W/HiAdSDK.jd:  Root obj class (class java.lang.Object) is invalid
2021-01-13 00:20:22.042 2138-2324 W/HiAdSDK.jd:  toJson jsex
```

PS. using `implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ads-lite:13.4.37.300'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the allowed enum values in AdParam.Builder, eg. setGender(int
> value)?

Please kindly refer to [com.huawei.hms.ads.Gender](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/cn/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/constant-values-0000001050167043-V5#ZH-CN_TOPIC_0000001057762938__section1313653919549)，value 0 is for MALE, value 1 is for FEMALE.

For more details, see API documentation [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/adparam-builder-0000001050066829-V5).

Comment: Any thoughts on the log output related to sex field not set/invalid in JSON?

Comment: BTW in the ads-base jar: @AllApi
public interface Gender {
  int UNKNOWN = 0;
  int MALE = 1;
  int FEMALE = 2;
}

Answer (score 0):

It seems you used old version from the link you posted.
Please refer to the info. [Here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/adparam-builder-0000001050066829-V5) for latest info for the service.

BTW, 1 or 2 are correct for the setGender(int value) function.
Please try after you use the latest Ads SDK and function as above.
Could you please share more detail logs if the error occurs again?

Comment: I've updated my question with module import description, is `13.4.37.300` outdated? BTW there's nothing on your link: "Coming soon..."

Comment: Just edited the link, please check again. I will look into this issue again tomorrow morning.

Comment: btw `13.4.37.300` is mentioned in the [guide](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/publisher-service-integrating-sdk-0000001050066913-V5). Let me know if it should be updated, thanks

Comment: in the updated URL Gender.MALE or FEMALE is also not mentioned. But it's ok since i've already found it in the jar with help of @shirley